# VBA object returned from a function is unavailable

Tags: excel, vba

Automation object created in function can be used within this function just fine.
But when i try to return it from this function and then use it in another function is becomes unavailable.

I know about the trick with passing object to which function return value should be assigned to by ByRef buy i'm wondering VBA doesn't allow to return object directly from function in my case.

Thanks.

UPD. Same issue with `querySelectorAll()` despite it's "static" list.

```
Function GetElementByClass(Html As String, ClassName As String) _
                           As IHTMLElementCollection

    Dim WebPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set WebPage = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    WebPage.body.innerHTML = Html

    'GetElementByClass is valid object
    Set GetElementByClass = WebPage.getElementsByClassName(ClassName)

End Function


Sub GetDataFromPage()

        Dim Element As IHTMLElementCollection

        'Element is Nothing here. Why?
        Set Element = GetElementByClass(Html, "relative")

End Sub
```

Comment: How `Html` does look in `GetDataFromPage()` `Sub`?

Comment: @FaneDuru Just a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because `WebPage` is a local variable of `GetElementByClass` and it gets destroyed at `End Function`. And because what you return `Set GetElementByClass = WebPage.getElementsByClassName(ClassName)` is member of that `WebPage` object it disappears at the moment the function ends too.

#### 1. Workaround

Declare your variable as public, so it does not get destroyed.

```
Option Explicit
Global WebPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Function GetElementByClass(Html As String, ClassName As String) _
                       As IHTMLElementCollection

    Set WebPage = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    WebPage.body.innerHTML = Html

    'GetElementByClass is valid object
    Set GetElementByClass = WebPage.getElementsByClassName(ClassName)
End Function
```

#### 2. Workaround

Or create the variable `WebPage` in `GetDataFromPage` and pass it as pararmeter:

```
Option Explicit

Function GetElementByClass(WebPage MSHTML.HTMLDocument, ClassName As String) _
                           As IHTMLElementCollection
    'GetElementByClass is valid object
    Set GetElementByClass = WebPage.getElementsByClassName(ClassName)
End Function


Sub GetDataFromPage()
    Dim WebPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Set WebPage = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    WebPage.body.innerHTML = Html

    Dim Element As IHTMLElementCollection

    'Element is Nothing here. Why?
    Set Element = GetElementByClass(WebPage, "relative")

End Sub
```

Check if that works.

Comment: Thanks! I know about this approaches. I'm not in favor of global variables, but 2nd point is OK if problem described is limitation of the VBA. I just though that objects returned by reference and therefore when i return WebPage.getElementsByClassName(ClassName) (this line returns diferent object, so WebPage can be set to Nothing at this moment already) object function returns reference to it.

Comment: Eventually i switched to 2nd approach... It seems that VBA only keeps reference to main object in case of COM automation.

Answer (score 0):

It can't work by creating the node list with `getElementsByClassName()`, because that creates a **live** node list. Those only works together with the whole document. But the document will lost when you leave the funkction. No document, no live node list.

I think you can solve the problem by using a statik node list which you can create with [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

The "trick" with ByRef is no trick. It's the only way you can handle objects between functions. It's not possible to handle an object by value.

Comment: Thanks! What do you mean by "because that creates a live node list"? getElementsByClassName() returns different object which shouldn't depend on WebPage anymore.

Comment: Yes, it depends on the web page. You can easily test this, because it is possible to address e.g. parent nodes from such a list. This is only possible because the list works with the document. Look at the first sentence from my link *The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a static (not live) NodeList ...*

Comment: @user2702866 The node list of elements that is createt with `getElementsByClassName()` only exists as long as the document `WebPage` exists. If you destroy the variable `WebPage` at `End Function` the list of elements gets destroyed too.

Comment: @Zwenn Oh, i see. Generally you can easily return objects from functions because they used by references but in this particular case since GetElementByClass depends on WebPage and after function is executed there's no references to WebPage (it's swept.) i getting this issue. Thanks Zwenn, PeH!

Comment: Still it's strange. getElementsByClassName() should keep reference to WebPage if it's "live" then after my custom GetElementByClass() function is executed i keep this reference to object from getElementsByClassName() which itself keep reference to WebPage.

Comment: @user2702866 But with the `End Function` of your custom function the `WebPage` object gets destroyed. Since `WebPage` in declared locally in this function in only lives inside that function. If it ends it immediately destroys the object `WebPage`. So the reference is then pointing to a destroyed object that cannot provide any live list anymore. That is why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ When we allocate WebPage it's allocated on the heap. Object will be removed while there's no references to it (VBA using reference counting). What i don't understand is that why VBA destroys object at the end of function despite the fact that function return reference to this WebPage object and therefore reference count is never dropped to 0.

Comment: @user2702866 It is like if you `Set ws = Workbooks("bookA").Worksheet("Sheet1")` and then close workbook `bookA`. There is still a reference `ws` pointing to `Sheet1` in `bookA` but since the workbook object is gone your reference `ws` which depends on it is gone too.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Seems logically correct. But as i see in this case WebPage which is COM object never released manually so should only be deleted whene has 0 references to it. Need to read about it deeply someday. Thanks PeH.